# What does $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone explain me what $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ actually means?
I know the definition, but I'm not really understanding in practice what it means.

Comment: Listing out the definition you are working with will help avoid confusion in case there are multiple possible definitions for this concept.

Comment: @abiessu  $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$  is the set of functions $f:\mathbb{N}→\mathbb{R}$

Comment: In other words it's the set of infinite sequences with real values.

Answer (score 4):

Formally, $X^Y$ is the set of all functions from $Y$ to $X$. (You can keep straight which is the base and which is the exponent by thinking about finite combinatorics: how many functions from a $3$-element set to a $2$-element set are there, $2^3$ or $3^2$?)

However, this can be difficult to visualize at first, especially if $Y$ is infinite; some infinite sets, including $\mathbb{N}$, allow more intuitive descriptions. In particular, you can think of $X^\mathbb{N}$ as the set of *infinite sequences of* elements of $X$. To see the connection, given a sequence $S$ of elements of a set $X$ think of the function $f_S:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$ sending $i$ to the $i$th term of the sequence $S$.

So $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ in particular is **the set of infinite sequences of real numbers**. These are things you've already played with, e.g. when constructing the reals via Cauchy *sequences* or when asking questions about convergence of *sequences*.